# How does BeautifulSoup get text from soup of HTML when given HTML data obtained from Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on scraping webpages developed on JS.
I am able to get the HTML content from the page, however when i visualise the BeautifulSoup content of it, the data seems to be missing the textual info and all I see is scripts info. (Image: soupstr output)
However, when I call .text explicitly to Beautiful soup object, i get all the text. (Image: souptext output)

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7QXQ.png)

[Image: soupstr output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuXYD.png)

[Image: souptext output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ0n1.png)

How can we get pure HTML data consisting HTML tags along with text (basically a replica of DOM) using Selenium Webdriver on Python?

PS: Sorry for non-inline images since i do not have the reputation yet to post inline messages.

Comment: try `print(soup)` this would give the html of the page

Comment: Print(soup) and visualizing str(soup) both give the same result for which I have attached the screenshot.

Comment: don't post images of your code. Include the code in your post. So how are you obtaining the html from selenium and how are you feeding that into beautifulsoup?

Comment: its most likely you need to get the page source from your webdriver: `soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')`

Comment: @chitown88 `driver.page_source` works well for non-javascript however, wont work for pages developed in javascript
For example this [javascript link](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/cricket/news/hasan-ali-takes-10-wickets-as-pakistan-sweep-test-series-vs-south-africa/articleshow/80748289.cms) wont work with your solution.

Comment: `driver.page_source` does work with javascript rendered pages. You need to allow the time for the page to render first. I can show you. What are you trying to get from this link?

Comment: secondly, you can obtain that article in the link you provided directly. No need to use selenium if that's what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
soup_page = BeautifulSoup(ele_html.content,"html.parser")
print(soup_page)
```